# "GoogleApiClient is not connected yet" exception in Cast application

Tags: android, google-cast, chromecast

I'm developing an Android application that casts content to Chromecast.
Sometimes in my `com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks` implementation in the `onConnected` method, I get a

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
```

exception.

Here is the stack trace:

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.joaomgcd.autocast, PID: 13771
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.eg.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.cast.Cast$CastApi$a.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.joaomgcd.autocast.media.MediaConnectionCallbacks.onConnected(MediaConnectionCallbacks.java:37)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.dx.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.bn(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.f(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$2.onConnected(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.dx.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.dx.bT(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.dw$h.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.dw$h.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.dw$b.bR(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.dw$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This only seems to happen if I had already connected to the GoogleApiClient before and am connecting for a second time. Between the 2 calls I disconnect from the api client with the code below.

My guess is that this is a bug. Am I correct? Since I'm in the `onConnected` method, the GoogleApiClient should already be connected.

What can I do to get around it? Should I just wait for a while until the GoogleApiClient is really connected?

I am doing this in a service and here are the relevant bits:

when the service starts:

```
mMediaRouter.addCallback(mMediaRouteSelector, mediaCallback, MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_PERFORM_ACTIVE_SCAN);
```

mediaCallback has this code:

```
@Override
    public void onRouteAdded(MediaRouter router, RouteInfo route) {
        super.onRouteAdded(router, route);
        if (route.getDescription().equals("Chromecast")) {
            ...
            mSelectedDevice = com.google.android.gms.cast.CastDevice.getFromBundle(route.getExtras());

            ...
                castClientListener = new CastListener(context, apiClient);

                Cast.CastOptions.Builder apiOptionsBuilder = Cast.CastOptions.builder(mSelectedDevice, castClientListener);
                ...
                apiClient.set(new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context).addApi(Cast.API, apiOptionsBuilder.build()).addConnectionCallbacks(connectionCallback).addOnConnectionFailedListener(new MediaConnectionFailedListener(context)).build());
                apiClient.get().connect();
        }

    }
```

connectionCallback has this code:

```
@Override
    public void onConnected(final Bundle arg0) {
        ...
            Cast.CastApi.launchApplication(apiClient, UtilAutoCast.CHROMECAST_APP_ID, false).setResultCallback(connectionCallback);
        ...
    }
```

The code above is the part where the crash happens.

And when I stop the service I run this code:

```
if (mMediaRouter != null) {
    mMediaRouter.removeCallback(mediaCallback);
    mMediaRouter = null;
}
if (apiClient != null) {
    Cast.CastApi.stopApplication(apiClient);
    if (apiClient.isConnected()) {
        apiClient.disconnect();
        apiClient = null;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add some code?

Comment: Connecting for a second time? Have you disconnected from the first one? Need more code from your side to see what is happening.

Comment: Please show us where you are connecting GoogleApiClient...

Answer (score 7):

[Google APIs for Android > GoogleApiClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html)

> You should instantiate a client object in your Activity's onCreate(Bundle) method and then call connect() in onStart() and disconnect() in onStop(), regardless of the state.

The implementation of the `GoogleApiClient` appears designed for only a single instance. It's best to instantiate it only once in `onCreate`, then perform connections and disconnections using the single instance.

I would guess that only one `GoogleApiClient` can be actually be connected, but multiple instances are receiving the `onConnected` callback.

In your case it's probably fine to not call `connect` in `onStart`, but only in `onRouteAdded`.

I think this issue is very similar to  [Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException GoogleApiClient is not connected yet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26998201/4107809)

Comment: Also from the examples you can use  .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */), which takes care of the connect() and disconnect() or so it seems.

Answer (score 5):

Have you declare following **`<meta>`** tag

```
<application ...> 
... 
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
... 
</application>
```

I just forgot to write so may you also stuck with this reason.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

From showcase app ([Googlecast Github Sample  CastHelloText-android](https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-android) ) receiver app is launched onRouteSelected (not onRouteAdded as you are doing in your code). I would try to change that. In case it does not work, I would add log lines in every method related to connection & session, and see what is happening.

Another tip: I have had crash with stopping the application (in case chromecast device is physically plugged out from power). Solution is to put`Cast.CastApi.stopApplication(apiClient);` inside `if (apiClient.isConnected())`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm running my app in a background service so I really need to connect to my Chromecast on Route Added. The user doesn't manually select a route in this case. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are calling GoogleApiClient before it is connected

move this line in onCreate()

```
// First we need to check availability of play services
    if (checkPlayServices()) {

        // Building the GoogleApi client
        //buildGoogleApiClient();
        try {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();

            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }catch (IllegalStateException e)
        {
            Log.e("IllegalStateException", e.toString());
        }
        createLocationRequest();
    }
```

Hope it helps you.