# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException GoogleApiClient is not connected yet

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

We have this crash in crashlytics, the weird thing is it happens in `onConnected()` callback when requesting location updates.

**Code:**

```
abstract public class MainService_6_LocationClient extends MainService_5_DriverGpsLocationStoring
    implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {


  private LocationListener highAccuracyListener;
  private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
  private LocationRequest gpsRequest;

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    lazyInit();
    googleApiClient.connect();
  }

  @Override public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnected");
    lazyInit();
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, gpsRequest,
          highAccuracyListener);
  }

  private void lazyInit() {

    if (highAccuracyListener == null) {
      highAccuracyListener = new HighAccuracyLocationListener();
    }

    if (googleApiClient == null) {
      googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(LocationServices.API)
          .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
          .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
          .build();
    }

    if (gpsRequest == null) {
      gpsRequest = new LocationRequest().setInterval(2000)
          .setFastestInterval(1000)
          .setSmallestDisplacement(0)
          .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }
  }

  @Override public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.w(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended");
    lazyInit();
    googleApiClient.reconnect();
  }

  @Override public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onConnectionFailed");
  }

  @Override public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");

    if (googleApiClient != null) {
      if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient,
            highAccuracyListener);
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
      }

      googleApiClient = null;
    }
    highAccuracyListener = null;
    gpsRequest = null;

    super.onDestroy();
  }
```

**Crash log:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.o.a()
       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.b.b()
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.lu.requestLocationUpdates()
       at ee.mtakso.driver.service.orderState.MainService_6_LocationClient.onConnected(MainService_6_LocationClient.java:33)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.f.d()
       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.b.gm()
       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.b.d()
       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.b$2.onConnected()
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.f.d()
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.f.dL()
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.e$h.b()
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.e$h.g()
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.e$b.gU()
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.e$a.handleMessage()
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4947)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Doesn't `onConnected()` imply **GoogleApiClient** is connected and ready to be used? How can I resolve this?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this problem?  I am seeing a similar occurrence in an emulator.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I got answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31691878/1318946

Answer (score 9):

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html

> You should instantiate a client object in your Activity's onCreate(Bundle) method and then call connect() in onStart() and disconnect() in onStop(), regardless of the state.

The implementation of the GoogleApiClient appears designed for only a single instance. It's best to instantiate it only once in onCreate, then perform connections and disconnections using the single instance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should notice, `GoogleApiClient.Builder` has a method `setAccountName()`. You should invoke this method with your Google account name. I have tried, and succeeded. I used the following code:

```
if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
       .addApi(LocationServices.API)
       .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
       .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
       .setAccountName("李江涛")
       .build();
}

if (mLocationRequest == null) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}
```

Comment: "your" account name doesn't matter. If you want to specify an account it hast to be on the user's device. You usually don't specify this because the user has to have a Google account to use play services on his device. This default account will be used if you don't set anything.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient` instead of `GoogleApiClient`.  Note that the `ConnectionCallbacks` and `OnConnectionFailedListener` interfaces that you implement will be slightly different.

Here's a quick example:

```java
class LocationHandler implements ConnectionCallbacks,
        OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private LocationClient client;

    void getLocation(Context context) {
        client = new LocationClient(context, this, this);
        client.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        LocationRequest request = LocationRequest.create();
        request.setNumUpdates(1);
        client.requestLocationUpdates(request, this);
        client.unregisterConnectionCallbacks(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() { }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // handle connection failure
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        client.removeLocationUpdates(this);
        client.disconnect();

        // do stuff with the location
    }

}
```

Comment: GoogleApiClient is the de facto api for location services nowadays.

Comment: Yep, it appears that LocationClient has been removed altogether.  At the time (and maybe this is still the case) the location services documentation still showed examples with LocationClient.  Looks like I fell victim to the same problem as [these people](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611977/android-locationclient-class-is-deprecated-but-used-in-documentation).