# Wait for GoogleAPIClient to load before trying to connect

Tags: android, google-maps, fusedlocationproviderapi

I'm building a simple map application using the Google Maps API. When I open the app it will sometimes crash because the GoogleApiClient is not connected yet. I have a few methods that run and need the API to be connected.

How do I prevent the crashes by waiting for the API to connect?

Here is some of my code:
onConnected:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint)
{
    // this callback will be invoked when all specified services are connected
    //Must ask for explicit permission
    //ie: Opening settings action in order to change or give permissions
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        currentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleClient);
        mGoogleClient.connect();

        if (currentLocation != null)
        { 
            currentLatLng = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLatLng, 15));
        } 

        else
        {
           if (mGoogleClient!=null )
           {
               mGoogleClient.connect();
           }

            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleClient, locationRequest, this);

        }
    }
}
```

Getting the current location:

```
private void getLocation() {

    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(60 * 1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(30 * 1000);

    mGoogleClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

    if (mGoogleClient != null)
    {
        mGoogleClient.connect();
    }


}
```

I'm not sure what else is needed. Please let me know if I need to provide more code.

Edit: Crash log

```
08-15 17:51:54.692 950-950/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                           Process: com.hensh.fusedmap, PID: 950
                                           java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
                                               at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzh.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                               at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzl.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                               at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzj.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                               at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzd.requestLocationUpdates(Unknown Source)
                                               at com.hensh.fusedmap.MapsActivity.onConnected(MapsActivity.java:667)
                                               at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzk.zzk(Unknown Source)
                                               at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzj.zzi(Unknown Source)
                                               at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzh.zzpx(Unknown Source)
                                               at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzh.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                                               at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzl.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                                               at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzc.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                                               at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzg.zzqL(Unknown Source)
                                               at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zza.zzc(Unknown Source)
                                               at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zza.zzw(Unknown Source)
                                               at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzc.zzqN(Unknown Source)
                                               at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5294)
                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

Comment: I guess your map is not ready and results in a crash because your code for getting the location is okay.

Comment: please specify where it crashes. Also why are you calling connect `mGoogleClient.connect();` in your onConnected?

Comment: Crash log has been added. the onConnected method is more of a "let's connect now". It crashes when the app opens (but after a while it runs fine)

Comment: @PatrickZenker that's what I want to fix, how can I wait until the map is ready before running any more code

Comment: Your onConnected method is called because, before, somewhere in your code, you called mGoogleClient.connect(). So you should not call again connect() inside onConnected.

Comment: To wait for the map to be ready, you can use MapFragment.getAsync or GoogleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback

Comment: Unclear exactly where you went wrong, but take a look at this working example for a reference: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/170/google-maps-api-v2-for-android/5557/show-current-location-in-a-google-map#t=201608151922003393625

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GoogleAPIClient` needs to be connected before you try to use the service. So your call to connect it in the `onConnected` is wrong. If you're in `onConnected` it means the client *is* connected. You need to build the `GoogleAPIClient` in the `onCreate` of your activity and ideally connect it in the `onStart` of your `Activity`.

```
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.<your-xml>);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
             .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
             .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
             .addApi(LocationServices.API)
             .build();
}
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

Additionally, when building the `GoogleAPIClient` you can also set `enableAutoManage()` for the `connect` and `disconnect` to be managed automatically so that you dont have to do it manually, as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient).

```
public class LocationActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    /** Google Services client */
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.payment_activity);
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                 .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                 .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                 .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                 .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should place the code snippet `mMap.animateCamera...` etc into onMapLoaded.

[Detect when Android v2 maps has loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18432853/6161100)

And remove `mGoogleClient.connect();` in your onConnected method because you don't have to connect twice (or more)

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear how you want your application to function. If you want your location to be displayed on the map and updated when you move:

1. Instantiate `GoogleApiClient` only once in `onCreate`.
2. Connect `GoogleApiClient` in `onResume`.
3. In `onConnected`, make your location request(s)
4. In `onLocationChanged`, move your map.

It's probably worthwhile to review: [Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException GoogleApiClient is not connected yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998201/fatal-exception-java-lang-illegalstateexception-googleapiclient-is-not-connecte)