# Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception

I am having trouble submitting the highscores to android leaderboards.  Right now the leaderboards are empty and nothing is being submitted.  I have an int "oldScore" that needs to be submitted.  Right now I am trying a piece of code to submit it but the activity crashes when called. My code:

```
public class GameOver extends BaseGameActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    public static int score;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_over);

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(Drive.API)
        .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();

        int newScore = GameOver.score;

        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        int oldScore = prefs.getInt("key", 0);
        if (newScore > oldScore) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
            edit.putInt("key", newScore);
            edit.commit();

            EditText HighScore = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.HighScoreT);
            HighScore.setText("" + newScore);
        } else {
            EditText HighScore = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.HighScoreT);
            HighScore.setText("" + oldScore);
            Games.Leaderboards.submitScoreImmediate(getApiClient(),String.valueOf(R.string.number_guesses_leaderboard), oldScore);
        }
    }
```

Logcat:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface
>   method 'void
>   com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.connect()' on a null
>   object reference

Answer (score 11):

The statement

```
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

should appear after `mGoogleApiClient` has been instantiated

Comment: When I do this I then get this error : "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet."

Answer (score 9):

You are invoking the method

```
connect()
```

on the object

```
mGoogleApiClient
```

without instantiating it

You need to write this first,

```
  mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
```

then this,

```
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

Comment: When I do this I then get this error : "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet."

Comment: You are using the google login,
You should call the method from onStart()

Comment: I just created methods onStart() and onStop() and put mGoogleApiClient.connect(); in OnStart yet i am getting the same error.

Comment: when i delete "Games.Leaderboards.submitScoreImmediate(getApiClient(), String.valueOf(R.string.number_guesses_leaderboard), oldScore);" my activity works fine.. so this is where my error is coming from.  How should i change this to submit the score?

Answer (score 2):

You can't call `connect()` until *after* you initialize the `mGoogleApiClient` reference. Like,

```
// mGoogleApiClient.connect();
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();       
mGoogleApiClient.connect(); // <-- move to here.
```

Comment: When I do this I then get this error : "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet."

Comment: Okay. That sounds like we've fixed your `NullPointerException`. Have you done any research at all on your [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21831224/googleapiclient-is-not-connected-yet-exception-in-cast-application)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this process :
Assign google client before loading contentview:

```
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
public static int score;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addApi(Drive.API)
    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .build();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_over);
}
```

Add override onStart and connect the google client.

```
@Override
     public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}
```