# GoogleApiClient is not connected yet

Tags: java, android, google-api

My app was working until yesterday when i started the following:

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
> ```

Has anyone every come accross this?

Comment: Could you perhaps place the code that the error mentioned, and not all of it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with debugging in Java as I am new to it, where would I look?

Comment: Try checking this question out (there are many like it when you google that error ;) ): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474986/android-google-play-games-services-connection-error-java-lang-illegalstateexc

Comment: I got solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/31691878/1318946 @MattJameson