# Initialing GoogleApiClient after boot

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, google-api-client

I'm registering my app after boot to receive location updates. My boot receiver is starting a service that does the initialization:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
 GoogleApiClient client = _googleApiBuilder.get()
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

 client.connect();
}
```

Sometimes in the `onConnected`   callback method I'm getting exception indication I'm not connected yet. After some research I've encountered this - [GoogleApiClient is throwing "GoogleApiClient is not connected yet" AFTER onConnected function getting called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29343922/googleapiclient-is-throwing-googleapiclient-is-not-connected-yet-after-onconne)

It made me think, does the way I'm initializing google api is correct ? e.g. should I initialize it in a service ?

What is the suggested way to do it in the background ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will be helpful to you.

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements ConnectionCallbacks,
    OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

private static final String TAG = LocationService.class.getSimpleName();
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(final Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    initGoogleApi();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags,
        final int startId) {
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(final ConnectionResult result) {
}

@Override
public void onConnected(final Bundle bundale) {
    createLocationRequest();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(final int arg0) {
}

protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, this);
}

protected void createLocationRequest() {
    final LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(Constants.INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(Constants.FAST_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0);
    startLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest);
}

private void initGoogleApi() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API).addApi(ActivityRecognition.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
}

}
```

Comment: can you explain the rational behind what you wrote? in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29343922/googleapiclient-is-throwing-googleapiclient-is-not-connected-yet-after-onconne they suggest something else.

Comment: I suggested way of nitializing google api using service

Answer (score 0):

Used the following solution instead:

```
googleApiInstance.blockingConnect(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

or in other words instead of running the operation in a different thread (that's what `connect` is doing), I'm running it in my own thread (I'm using `IntentService`) and manage the connection life cycle on my own.