# How to make Log Out from Google LogIn?

Tags: java, android

According to google docx we have two methods

- SingOut
- RevokeAccess

I need second one

For this way google provide such method

```
public void revokeAccess() {
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = getGoogleSignInOptions();
    mGoogleApiClient = getGoogleApiClient(gso);
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                        Logger.log(GoogleImplementation.class, "signOut:onResult:" + status, Logger.ERROR);
                    }
                });
    } else {
        Logger.log(GoogleImplementation.class, "GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.", Logger.ERROR);
    }
}
```

But everytime when i try to invoke it i get error

> GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.

I found [the same issue on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29343922/googleapiclient-is-throwing-googleapiclient-is-not-connected-yet-after-onconne) and according to this as far as i understand i have to invoke `revokeAccess()` on the same object which i made `LogIn()`

Therefore question how i can to save this object? Or i misunderstand the consept?

What am i doing wrong?

**EDIT**

```
@NonNull
public GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient(GoogleSignInOptions gso) {
    return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .enableAutoManage(activity, listenerConnection)   <-----
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
}
```

**EDIT 2**

```
public void revokeAccess() {
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = getGoogleSignInOptions();
    mGoogleApiClient = getGoogleApiClient(gso);
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                        Logger.log(GoogleImplementation.class, "signOut:onResult:" + status, Logger.ERROR);
                    }
                });
    } else {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        Logger.log(GoogleImplementation.class, "GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.", Logger.ERROR);
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                        Logger.log(GoogleImplementation.class, "signOut:onResult:" + status, Logger.ERROR);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In each different activity, You should connect your GoogleApiClient,  it will not stay connected across activities.

Comment: you mean if i make log in on one activity and then i go to another one i have to make `mGoogleApiClient.connected()`?

Comment: Exactly, but you can do this using automanage thne you connect once selecting your account and after that it connect automaticcaly nothing displayed on UI.

Comment: i edited my question. There is a line that i marked `<------` , you mean i have to use it instead of  `mGoogleApiClient.connected()`? But i have already use it and still get error

Comment: look please on my edit 2. When i try invoke `revokeAccess()` method i try to check `mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()` if not i try make `mGoogleApiClient.connect();` and then again `revokeAccess` but i still get error(( What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have onActivityResult and check for RC_SIGN_IN in order to perform 

GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);

Comment: Then dont know why you cant connect, you have done that ? https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123841/discussion-between-hugo-houyez-and-aleksey-timoshchenko).

Comment: yes sure i have done, i get access and i get tokenId and all are working perfect, but issue came when i try to revoke(