# java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet. in Map page not properly

Tags: android, google-api-client

I'm using `mapbox` in my mobile to fetch the current location but sometimes it's showing the marker and in logcat its showing as java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.

Note when I click that line in logcat it goes to this code

```
@Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                return;
            }
            if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient,
                    REQUEST,
                    this);  // LocationListener

    }
```

This is my java code:

```
public class ClockInDetails extends Fragment implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
    private MapboxMap mMapBoxMap;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = null;
    private LatLng gs_var_mLatLng;
    private MarkerOptions mMarker;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }
    private static final LocationRequest REQUEST = LocationRequest.create()
            .setInterval(5000)
            .setFastestInterval(5000)
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    public ClockInDetails() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    public static boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    public static boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Mapbox.getInstance(getContext(), getString(R.string.access_token));

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_clock_in_details, container, false);
        try {
            gs_mapView = (MapView)view.findViewById(R.id.gs_mapView);
            //to check gps is enabled or not

            gs_mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //mapbox view to display current locations by calling buildgooglepaiclient
            gs_mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
                    mMapBoxMap = mapboxMap;
                    buildGoogleApiClient();
                    mapboxMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                }
            });
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);



            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_confirmation);

                TextView tv_alert_Message = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.message);

                tv_alert_Message.setText("GPS has been disabled in your device. Please enable it?");
                Button btn_submit = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok);
                Button btn_cancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);


                btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                btn_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        getContext().startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);


                        buildGoogleApiClient();

                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();




            } else {
                mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
                        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                        .build();
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }


            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        gs_mapView.onStart();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        gs_mapView.onResume();
         if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        try {
            super.onPause();
 gs_mapView.onPause();
            if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        gs_mapView.onStop();
       if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        gs_mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
         gs_mapView.onDestroy();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        gs_mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    private synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        try {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void GS_Funtcion_updateCamera() {

        try {
            CameraPosition position = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(gs_var_mLatLng) // Sets the new camera position
                    .zoom(16) // Sets the zoom
                    .bearing(0) // Rotate the camera
                    .tilt(0) // Set the camera tilt
                    .build(); // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder

            mMapBoxMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(position), 1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void GS_Funtcion_updateMarker() {
        try {

            mMapBoxMap.clear();
            mMarker = new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(gs_var_mLatLng)
                    .title("Location")
                    .snippet("Welcome to you")
                    .icon(drawableToIcon(getContext(),ServerUtils.Gs_ImagePath+gs_var_user_image, 1));
            mMapBoxMap.addMarker(mMarker);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void GS_Funtcion_addMarker() {
        try {

            gs_var_latitude = gs_var_mLatLng.getLatitude();
            gs_var_longitude = gs_var_mLatLng.getLongitude();
            mMarker = new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(gs_var_mLatLng)
                    .title("Location")
                    .snippet("Welcome to you")
                    .icon(drawableToIcon(getContext(),ServerUtils.Gs_ImagePath+gs_var_user_image, 1));
            mMapBoxMap.addMarker(mMarker);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        try {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient,
                    REQUEST,
                    this);  // LocationListener
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        try {
            Log.i("SS","loca--"+location);
            gs_var_mLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());


            GS_Funtcion_updateCamera();

            if (mMarker != null) {
                Log.i("SS","if---loca--"+location);
                GS_Funtcion_updateMarker();
            }else{
                GS_Funtcion_addMarker();
                Log.i("SS","else---loca--"+location);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }


    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                    }

                } else {
 }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }

}
```

I don't know why it's not showing even though the location is On, I connected the `googleApiClient` in `onStart()`, `onResume()` but why its showing not connected yet.Marker is not showing on the map.Please help me someone.
In Android 4.4 I have one alert to check gps is enable or not that popup is not showing.Please help me, what mistake I did, But sometimes marker its showing how?

logcat-image
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the logcat?

Comment: i added the image

Comment: Try moving requestLocationUpdates() in onConnected() to the IF statement checking for null google client.

Comment: Have you created your project in google developers console and added your SHA1 key with your package and retrieved your API key??

Comment: Yes created sometimes current location marker showing

Comment: @jelic98,I changed and checked still its not showing.if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                        mGoogleApiClient,
                        REQUEST,
                        this);  // LocationListener
            }
you said like this right?

Comment: @jelic98,I changed and checked still its not showing.if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                        mGoogleApiClient,
                        REQUEST,
                        this);  // LocationListener
            }
you said like this right?

Comment: check this      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29343922/googleapiclient-is-throwing-googleapiclient-is-not-connected-yet-after-onconne

Answer (score 0):

Before applying mGoogleApiClient.connect(); you should add a null check i.e. your code should look like this:

```
if(mGoogleApiClient!=null)
     mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

Comment: where i should add this one,already i'm checking googleapiclient==null

Comment: if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                        mGoogleApiClient,
                        REQUEST,
                        this);  // LocationListener
            }
am already checking in onconeected eventhough marker is not showing

Comment: Try to add it to the else method too